# SQL Error: ORA-12712: new character set must be a superset of old character set

Tags: oracle, utf-8

I want to change character set of oracle database from 'WE8MSWIN1252' to 'AL32UTF8'

I tried to execute following steps from the link (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm#1009580):

> Shut down the database, using either a SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE or a
>   SHUTDOWN NORMAL statement. Do a full backup of the database because
>   the ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET statement cannot be rolled back.
>   Complete the following statements:

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;
```

But when i execute the above statement, I am getting the following error

SQL Error: ORA-12712: new character set must be a superset of old character set

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET` statement to execute successfully, two conditions must be fulfilled:

- Each and every character in the current character set is available in the new character set.
- Each and every character in the current character set has the same code point value in the new character set. (ie: the old charset must be a subset of the new one)

Because `WE8MSWIN1252` is not a strict subset of `AL32UTF8` this statement will fail (example: the pound sign is `A3` in hex in `WE8MSWIN1252`, but in `AL32UTF8` it is `C2 A3`).

You'll need to use `CSALTER` to do this migration.

**Refer to: [Character Set Migration.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#CEGDHJFF)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I was using Oracle XE, so uninstalled it and installed Oracle XE universal... and this has changed my character set to UTF8.

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you should not use it. Actually these conditions are true only when the old character set is `US7ASCII` or your database is empty. However, when the database is empty then it would be safer to create just a new one.

Comment: The linked "Character Set Migration" page describes the CSALTER script as having the same restrictions as ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET though. So if ALTER DABATASE CHARACTER SET doesn't work, why would CSALTER work? Does CSALTER perhaps have the same "requirements" but its not enforced, doesn't error and only changes the metadata character set declaration?

Answer (score 6):

The Easiest way: **(Shutdown neccesary)**:

First, Connect as sysdba:

```
sqplus / as sysdba
```

Next, execute the following script:

```
alter system set nls_length_semantics=CHAR scope=both;
shutdown;
startup restrict;
alter database character set INTERNAL_USE WE8ISO8859P1;
shutdown;
startup;
```

It worked for me in a Oracle 12c Standard Two Edition

Taken from: https://www.elblogdelpibe.com/2015/05/como-solucionar-el-error-ora-12899.html (updated URL)

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thak you for your esay way of solution

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224015/oracle-11g-xe-greek-character-set-not-displaying). However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.

Answer (score 3):

## Below worked for me in 19C.

## Issue

import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
Warning: possible data loss in character set conversions

## Steps

Database started in Restriction mode.

SQL>  select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

### PARAMETER

### VALUE

NLS_CHARACTERSET
AL32UTF8

SQL> alter database character set WE8MSWIN1252;
alter database character set WE8MSWIN1252
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12712: new character set must be a superset of old character set

SQL> alter database character set INTERNAL_USE WE8MSWIN1252;

Database altered.

SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

### PARAMETER

### VALUE

NLS_CHARACTERSET
WE8MSWIN1252

SQL>

Cheers!
RaJ...

Answer (score 1):

replace line 6 by

`ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AL32UTF8;`

this solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
con 11g funciona
alter system set nls_length_semantics=CHAR scope=both;
shutdown;
startup restrict;
alter database character set INTERNAL_USE WE8ISO8859P1;
shutdown;
startup;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).